# Unexpected output from min_rank and filter

Tags: r

I am working through [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#exercises-10) and trying to find top 10 delayed flights.  I am using min_rank to create a ranking of each flight then trying to filter out the top 10. I am sure I am missing something simple but I am getting really odd results and would love an explanation why so I can avoid this in the future.

To filter out I have used x %in% var as well as == x but both give different results

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
x <- 1:10

select(flights, arr_delay, carrier) %>% 
  mutate(delay_rank = min_rank(desc(arr_delay))) %>% 
  filter(delay_rank == x %in% delay_rank)


select(flights, arr_delay, carrier) %>% 
         mutate(delay_rank = min_rank(desc(arr_delay))) %>% 
         filter(delay_rank == x)
```

The first block gives the number one result only, but not any of the other 9

The second block gives 9,8,4 but not any of the other top 10.

I am hoping for a tibble with the top 10 results.

Comment: I think you do't need  `delay_rank ==` try with `filter(delay_rank %in% x)`

Comment: Why does that work?  But it does! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple element comparison, we use `%in%` instead of `==`.  In the first try, there is no need for `delay_rank ==` , just using `delay_rank %in% x` would get extract the rows where 'delay_rank' matches one of the elements of 'x'

```
select(flights, arr_delay, carrier) %>% 
    mutate(delay_rank = min_rank(desc(arr_delay))) %>% 
    filter(delay_rank %in% x)
```

---

to understand how it works, check

```
(1:5) == (2:3)
```

Here, there is recycling of 2, 3, until the length of the lhs vector is met.  There would be a warning as well if the lengths of second vector recycling is not completed

```
(1:5) == c(2, 3, 2, 3, 2)
```

In the second case, with using `%in%`

```
(1:5) %in% (2:3)
```

it checks for numbers 2, 3 to match anywhere in the vector

Comment: I still have much to learn but thanks for the explanation and answer.  Ill mark correct once I get past the time limit!